# Modify Mysql column from Time to Integer ( seconds ) converting time value to seconds

Tags: mysql

I am trying to modify mysql column from Time to integer ( seconds ).
For example I have value 22:01:42 in Time column. After running `ALTER TABLE 'table'  MODIFY 'column' INTEGER;` I am getting as result 220142. I want to convert TIME value to seconds while modifying. Thanks for help!

Comment: Do you mean you want to hold ONLY the seconds part of the time i.e. 42, or convert the time into a number of seconds? If the second, convert the time to a number of second SINCE WHEN?

Comment: Convert the 22:01:42 to seconds. The whole value, not just seconds, thanks. Convert hours, minutes and seconds to seconds. for example if my value is 00:01:05 then the after convertion I should get 65.

Comment: Thanks for reply. This is duration time, for example 22:01:42 means that duration was 22 hours, 1 minute, 42 seconds. I want to keep this duration converted to seconds. In the same column modifying column's DATA type from TIME to INTEGER ( seconds)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple way, create a new column let call it `duration` as integer.

run a simple update

```
update table set `duration` = TIME_TO_SEC(existing_column);
```

check it all worked, then drop the `existing_column` and then rename the `duration` column to `existing_column` if you want to keep the original column name.